# Haystack says “Model could not be found for SearchResult”

Tags: python, django, nginx, solr, django-haystack

After updating my Django from 1.7 to 1.9, search engine, which is based on Haystack and Solr, stopped working. This is what I get:

```
./manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>>sqs[0].pk
u'1'
>>> sqs[0].text
u'\u06a9\u0627\u0645\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0647\u0645\u062a\u200c\u067e\u0648\u0631 \u0648 \u0641\u0631\u0647\u0627\u062f \u0628\u0627\u062f\u067e\u0627\nKamran Hematpour &amp; Farhad Badpa'
>>> sqs[0].model_name
u'artist'
>>> sqs[0].id
u'mediainfo.artist.1'
>>> sqs[0].object
Model could not be found for SearchResult '<SearchResult: mediainfo.artist (pk=u'1')>'.
```

I have to say my database is not empy and my configuration is as follow:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS ={
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://ahangsolr:8983/solr',
    },
}
```

And this is my `search_indexes.py`:

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from mediainfo.models import Album
from mediainfo.models import Artist
from mediainfo.models import PlayList
from mediainfo.models import Track
from mediainfo.models import Lyric

class AlbumIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    artist = indexes.CharField(model_attr='artist', indexed=True)
    publish_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Album

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(publish_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())


class ArtistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Artist


class PlaylistIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return PlayList


class TrackIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Track


class LyricIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Lyric
```

Comment: What version of Haystack are you using?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco haystack 2.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by including a missing commit to the 2.4.1 release. The commit that fixed this issue was https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/commit/f1ed18313777005dd77ed724ecbfb27c0b03cad8

so you can do

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack.git@f1ed18313777005dd77ed724ecbfb27c0b03cad8
```

to install until that specific commit.

Comment: Thanks @elchudi that was my answer but I added some changes to it : pip install git+https://git@github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack.git@master it really really did work

Comment: you're welcome golden_boy615 , I would not track @master in pip since master will change all the time, and until a new release of django-haystack it's better to just track a specific commit that you know it works

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to start checking the app registry to make sure it can find your model (just to be sure).

```
from django.apps import apps as django_apps
model = django_apps.get_model('mediainfo.artist')
model.app_label, model.model_name
assert model._meta.app_label == 'mediainfo'
assert model._meta.model_name == 'artist'
```

Then I would check what `haystack` is returning.

```
from haystack.utils.app_loading import haystack_get_model
haystack_model = haystack_get_model('mediainfo', 'artist')
haystack_model == model
```

If that doesn't return the same thing (`haystack_model` != `model`); then you will need to dig further.

However, loading and looking up models changed between `django` 1.7.0 and 1.8.0 (deprecation), and `django.db.models.loading.get_model` was removed in 1.8.2.
Details on [`django-haystack` #1206](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1206).

Therefore, for `django-haystack` to work with `django` 1.9.0 you need a release that includes [this commit](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/commit/ad90028a22b4274b8df1f4698dd59ac0643f03d5); that is to say `django-haystack>=2.4.0`.

Comment: my haystack version is 2.4.1 and  django_apps.get_model('mediainfo.artist') returns with No error: <class 'mediainfo.models.Artist'>. Anything else that I can provide for more information to help solving this issue?

Comment: haystack_model == model returns True but there is an error here when using app_label and model_name attribute of model:AttributeError: type object 'Artist' has no attribute 'model_name'   and   AttributeError: type object 'Artist' has no attribute 'app_label' !!!

Comment: facing this issue too - did you get a fix? for me haystack_model == model and this issue persists